# auth0 get further information about userProfile in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, auth0

I'm working with Auth0 and Android. My purpose is to retrieve more information about user, more than Email and Name,like for exemple the user's birthday. But I can not doing that even any other filed
When I've log the userProfile object; I've got all information which I like to have. but when I like to display for exemple the birthday in textView; I got this error

```
error: cannot find symbol method getGender()
```

this is how I write the simple piece of code:

```
birthdayTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.birthday), userProfile.getGender()));
```

Comment: looks like the compiler complains that it cannot find a method named getGender() - is there a reason you are calling the gender when displaying the birthday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is no `userProfile.getGender()` function.

The Auth0 normalized user profile contains [these attributes](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile/user-profile-structure).

Copying below for completeness. But note that `gender` is not available.

Possible work-arounds:

a). It is possible to add custom claims to `user_metadata` (editable by end user) or `app_metadata` (not editable by end user).

b). It is also possible to add a custom claim to a token via a Rule.

**Normalised User Profile Claims**

```
app_metadata: the custom fields storing information about a user. These attributes contain information that influences the user's access;

blocked*: the true/false value indicating if the user has been blocked;

created_at: the timestamp of when the user profile was first created;

email (unique): the user's email address

email_verified: the true/false value indicating if the user has verified their email address;

identities: the array of objects with information about the user's identities:

connection: the name of the connection used to authenticate the user;
isSocial: the true/false value indicating if the connection is a social one or not;
provider: the entity that is authenticating the user (such as Facebook, Twitter, and so on);
user_id: the user's unique identifier for this connection/provider.
multifactor: the list of multifactor providers in which the user is enrolled;

last_ip*: the IP address associated with the user's last login;

last_login*: the timestamp of when the user last logged in;

logins_count*: the number of times the user has logged in;

name: the user's name;

nickname: the user's nickname;

phone_number: the user's phone number;

phone_verified: the true/false value indicating whether the user's phone number has been verified (only valid for users with SMS connections);

picture: the user's profile picture, click here to learn more about the picture field;

updated_at: the timestamp of when the user's profile was last updated/modified;

user_id (unique): the user's unique identifier;

user_metadata: the custom fields storing information about a user. These attributes should contain information about the user that does not impact what they can or cannot access (such as work and home addresses);

username (unique): the user's username.
```

Comment: Thanks , But I would like to know how can I access to the user_id

Comment: Imen, thanks for acknowledging answer. Re. question - in the response, do you see `sub` (subject)?  The id token `sub` claim is the user id also if you can parse from the id token.